# pandas crosstab: include all levels

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

From the pandas docs of `pd.crosstab`:

"Any input passed containing Categorical data will have **all** of its categories included in the cross-tabulation, even if the actual data does not contain any instances of a particular category."

So what am I actually doing wrong in the code snippet below (the final output does not contain all levels)

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.api.types import CategoricalDtype as CD
ctype = CD(categories=["a","b","c"])
d_cat = pd.DataFrame({"x": ["a","a","a"], "y": ["b","a","b"]}, dtype=ctype)
d_cat["x"].dtype  # category
d_cat["x"].value_counts() # this properly includes all the levels - even unused
pd.crosstab(index=d_cat["x"], columns=d_cat["y"])
#y  a  b
#x
#a  1  2
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `dropna=False` as described in the [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) documentation:

```
pd.crosstab(index=d_cat['x'], columns=d_cat['y'], dropna=False)
```

Output:

```
y  a  b  c
x         
a  1  2  0
b  0  0  0
c  0  0  0
```

Example from the documentation:

> Here ‘c’ and ‘f’ are not represented in the data and will not be shown
> in the output because dropna is True by default. Set dropna=False to
> preserve categories with no data.
>
> ```
> >>> foo = pd.Categorical(['a', 'b'], categories=['a', 'b', 'c'])
> >>> bar = pd.Categorical(['d', 'e'], categories=['d', 'e', 'f'])
> >>> pd.crosstab(foo, bar)
> col_0  d  e
> row_0
> a      1  0
> b      0  1
> >>> pd.crosstab(foo, bar, dropna=False)
> col_0  d  e  f
> row_0
> a      1  0  0
> b      0  1  0
> c      0  0  0
> ```

Comment: Many thanks. But this is a bit weird. I always read "na" as missing values. But here there are no missing values. We have fully observed data - yet I have to specify an action involving na-values

Comment: I think this makes sense, it's however not consistent with other functions. `pivot_table` uses `observed=False` for instance.